# Using razer Core X with amd 5700 XT on Mac

Tags: hardware

Hi I'm on the verge of getting an eGPU Razer Core X and an AMD 5700 XT on macbook pro 15" 2.6 GHz Intel Core i7 32 G RAM for archviz but I need to make sure it's compatible with Blender

Comment: Don't. GPU rendering with Cycles on macOS is not possible, because Apple has deprecated OpenCL. Unless you want to use a third-party render engine that supports Metal, like AMD Radeon ProRender, it's not advisable.

Comment: That's what I thought... Looks like I'm going to have to get a whole new pc.

Comment: The requirements for GPU rendering are documented [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware). The minimum requirements for running Blender 2.8x can be found [here](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/).

Comment: I've read all this. And my specs are actually not that bad, just a little short for big scenes. There is also this script that I can tyoe to use a Nvidia card. My integrated 4g ram GPU gonna do the job until it can't I guess

Comment: I just downloaded amd prorender and I think I'm gonna work with it. What do you think and what would you do?